# How to use SQL IN statement in fsharp.data.sqlclient?

Tags: f#, fsharp.data.sqlclient

I have the following sample code. The objective is to run SQL statement with multiple input parameters.

```
[<Literal>]
let connectionString = @"Data Source=Localhost;Initial Catalog=Instrument;Integrated Security=True"
[<Literal>]
let query = "SELECT MacroName, MacroCode FROM Instrument WHERE MacroCode IN (@codeName)"

type MacroQuery = SqlCommandProvider<query, connectionString>
let cmd = new MacroQuery()
let res = cmd.AsyncExecute(codeName= [|"CPI";"GDP"|]) |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

However, codeName is inferred to be string type instead of an array or list and give me an error.

Alternatively, I could run the query without where statement and filter based on the result. However, in lots of other cases that returns millions of rows, I would prefer filter data at the SQL server level to be more efficient.

I didn't find any relevant samples on the documentation of fsharp.data.sqlclient. Please help!

Comment: I assume you're targeting SQL Server. Well, the reason that it's not using an array or list is simple - SQL Server doesn't have such data types. It has one data type specifically designed for storing multiple items of data - the table. I'm not familiar with [tag:fsharp.data.sqlclient], but I'd recommend you try to find out how to pass table-valued parameters to it.

Answer (score 6):

"See Table-valued parameters (TVPs)" section in the documentation: 
http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/configuration%20and%20input.html

Comment: So you have to put your query into a stored procedure, AND create a custom SQL type just to use an IN statement? Yuck.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an upper bound *n* on the values in the `IN` list, you could just make *n* parameters. If that's unmanageable, I'm afraid the TVP suggestion is your best option. The reason the FSharp.Data.SqlClient library is unlikely to ever support this directly is because the types are generated based on results from [sp_describe_undeclared_parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878260.aspx); there's no T-SQL parser. We had a single digit upper bound in this scenario and were loathe to change the database, so this option worked for us.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to abstract away the use of table-valued parameters. It seems you have to also declare the param first.

```
DECLARE @param varchar(1000) = @commaSeparatedList
SELECT Col1 FROM MyTable
WHERE Col2 IN (
  SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@param, ',')
)
```

Comment: This is cool but note that STRING_SPLIT requires compatibility level 130, i.e. SQL Server 2016 minimum.